# Ruby YAML serialization

Tags: ruby, serialization, yaml

I'm serializing a ruby object with

```
YAML::dump(obj)
```

and storing it in a database.
Then I'm calling

```
myobj = YAML::load(obj)
```

I can see in debug that the object was succesfully created and it's fields were initialized.
But when I'm trying to call an attribute, for example "name" like myobj.name, I recieve a "no method error" message. What am I doing wrong, and how can I correctly deserialize the object?BTW I can access fields of my object by calling

```
myobj.instance_variable_get('@attributes')[:name]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Just simple ruby class with fields

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't post full code of my class, because all code under NDA(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure your object has a method `name`?

Can you try a

```
YAML::dump(obj) 
p obj.name
```

Just to be sure, the object you store has really a method `name`.

Your

```
myobj.instance_variable_get('@attributes')[:name]
```

doesn't indicate, that there is a method or attribute `name`. There is only an attribute `@attributes`, that supports a method `[]` (probably a hash).

Perhaps you can use

```
myobj.attributes[:name]
```

But without more information, all this are only a guess.

Comment: myobj.attributes and p obj.name returns undefined method attributes, and undefined method name because I think myobj is not a AR object, just a class.In my class I have class MyClass
      ATTRIBUTES_KEYS = %w(id name surname)

Comment: When you define attributes with `ATTRIBUTES_KEYS` - do you also define accessor methods?

Comment: @Marat_Galiev: So the `p obj.name` will show you the problem and my answer is the solution - so you may accept my answer.